# What is the hash of a disengaged std::optional<T> object?

Tags: c++, hash, standard-library, option-type, c++14

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/hash) from cppreference mentions that `std::hash` has been specialized for `std::optional`, but doesn’t specify the behavior when the object is disengaged. I can think of different behaviors:

- It could throw a `std::bad_optional_access`, to be consistent with `std::optional::value`
- It could return the same hash for every disengaged `std::optional<T>`, this way 2 disengaged object would have the same hash.
- It could return a `std::optional<std::hash<std::optional<T>>>`

Comment: The last one is funny, but doesn't actually make sense :-S Weird, though, that this isn't specified. Then again, the language isn't published yet. How does Boost do it?

Comment: Note that `optional` was removed from C++14.

Comment: @Simple It was? Do you happen to have a link to the report with rationale? I would love to know

Comment: All I was able to find was [a fairly recent (2013-09-01) paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3765.pdf) discussing the pitfalls of `optional<bool>`, but nothing that would hint it wouldn't make it into C++14.

Comment: I saw it on isocpp.org yesterday that `optional` was removed from the standard and was heading for its own TS, but I can't find the article on there anymore. The minutes from the chicago meeting aren't up yet either (they usually get uploaded).

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) also confirms that it has since been removed.

Comment: wow ... and optional hash for an optional object into an optional container for an optional library linked to an optional program running into an optional OS !  Meta-programming to the 6th power!

Comment: It has been removed from the C++14 draft and will be in a separate "Library Fundamentals" TS. There are too many open questions and no consensus regarding how to define comparisons for `optional`, see [N3764](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3764.html) and [N3765](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3765.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++14 CD said in [optional.hash]/3:

> For an object `o` of type `optional<T>`, if `bool(o) == true`, `hash<optional<T>>()(o)` shall evaluate to the same value as `hash<T>()(*o)`.

So I would say it's unspecified what the hash function returns for a disengaged object.

Comment: so computing the hash of an `optional<T>` is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @qdii, unspecified is not the same as undefined. After inserting an element into a default-constructed `std::vector` the vector's capacity is _unspecified_, because it could take any value greater than zero, but it's not undefined behaviour to use the vector.  If `hash<optional<T>>` had a _Requires_ clause stating a precondition I would agree it's undefined, but as it is I'm not sure. I certainly don't think undefined behaviour was intended.

Comment: This is now [LWG2333](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2333) and will be addressed in the Library Fundamentals TS that specifies `std::experimental::optional`

Comment: The actual text in the resolution is "otherwise it evaluates to an unspecified value.". So it's actually pretty clear that it's not undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is relevant anymore, as C++14 does not have `std::optional` ultimately. The intention (although not reflected in the standardese initially) has always been that the hash of a disengaged optional object returns an unspecified value, as Jonathan said.

This intent is reflected in the [Fundamentals TS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v2/fundamentals-ts.html).

The idea is that the implementation of the Standard Library chooses how it wants to represent a disengaged `optional<T>` and documents it itself. It can choose a different value for different types, and also a different value in debug and release mode.